# Как поместить название базы в переменную?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как поместить название базы в переменную?
Есть процедура с жестко забитыми базами, а нужно динамически, что то на подобии:

```
процедура @имяБазы1 @имябазы2
SELECT * FROM @имяБазы1.таблица
SELECT * FROM @имяБазы2.таблица
```

Динамически стоить вариант не подходит

Comment: а по какой причине вам динамика не подходит? вложите динамическое образование внутрь ХП и нет проблем

Comment: Теряется читабельность кода. В процедуру приходят еще переменные, которые из динамического запроса не видны, а конкатенация строки запроса с переменными выглядит ужасно.

Comment: но это нормальная, используемая практика, один раз хорошо написать, отладить и забыть

Answer (score 2):

Только через динамику:

```
declare @basename nvarchar(100),@sql nvarchar(500)
select @basename = '[YouDB]'
select @sql = 'select * from '+@basename+'.[dbo].[YouTable]'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

а там уже можно куда угодно